# How to customize mass email in Outlook using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Is it possible to intercept Outlook's send event and contextually inject something into each message body? For instance, let's say I want to customize each message to begin with "Dear [name], ", and the To field contains "Mary, Jane", then Mary's email would read "Dear Mary, [body text]", etc. The only way I can think to do this is to create my own Send button and then with MySendButton_Click loop through each recipient and send a modified email to each person individually. The problem with that approach is that the user cannot see or interact with the full recipient list.

Comment: Why not set this up in Word? Mailmerge is one of Word's intended purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [Outlook mail merge](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/outlook/archive/2008/09/23/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx) or you can develop a mail merge application in vbscript or some other language.

Trying to modify the output of Outlook before it goes to the mail server would be rather difficult to get correct.